# eBay API ReviseItem call using cURL returns Serious Error #5 and #10012

Tags: php, xml, curl, ebay-api

I'm developing some PHP to work with the eBay API with cURL and I have tried this:

```
<?php
    $dev_id = "sandboxDevId"; //Changed for security reasons
    $app_id = "sandboxAppId"; //Changed for security reasons
    $cert_id = "sandboxCertId"; //Changed for security reasons

    $site_id = "186"; //spain

    $xmlVersion = "1.0";
    $encoding = "utf-8";

    $api_endpoint = "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll";
    $auth_token = "theAuthToken"; //The Auth token (Long String) for the seller user.
                                  //I have changed it for the real token
    $itemid = "110178474743"; //The item id in sandbox
    $new_description = "Updating my item description with cURL";
    $new_description = urldecode($new_description);

    $stringXML  = "<?xml version=\"".$xmlVersion."\" encoding=\"".$encoding."\"?>";
    $stringXML .="<ReviseItemRequest xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\">";
    $stringXML .="<ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage><Item><ItemID>".$itemid."</ItemID>";
    $stringXML .="<Description>".$new_description."</Description>";
    $stringXML .="</Item><RequesterCredentials>";
    $stringXML .="<eBayAuthToken>".$auth_token."</eBayAuthToken></RequesterCredentials>";
    $stringXML .="<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel></ReviseItemRequest>";

    $feed = new SimpleXMLElement($stringXML);

    $headers = array
        (
        'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: 963',
        'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: ' . $dev_id,
        'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: ' . $app_id,
        'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: '. $cert_id,
        'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: ReviseItem',
        'X-EBAY-API-SITEID: ' . $site_id,
    );

    $connection = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $feed);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($connection);

    curl_close($connection);
    echo $response;
?>
```

I have tried to change the item description via the Developer tool and it worked, and I have printed the XML as plain text and it seems to be correct, but for some reason i get the following error:

```
2016-05-26 08:38:32 100121SeriousError00RequestError 51SeriousError00RequestError
```

**It drops me two errors, i have checked them on the API reference:**

```
 #5 Serious error:  XML Parse error.
```

and

```
 #10012 Serious error: Invalid value for header "replaceable_value".
```

And i can't figure out how to solve that problems.

It will be helpful if someone can throw some light about this problem; It is the first time I work with cURL and XML and every help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
#10012 Serious error: Invalid value for header "replaceable_value".
```

I just had to inspect the element locally (F12 on browser) and it says that the error comes from the API detail level.

I added the following config line to the headers:

```
X-EBAY-API-DETAIL-LEVEL: 0;
```

and error #10012 seems to be solved.

Error #5 appeared because i was sending the XML to eBay servers the wrong way. I just had to pass the string to the cURL as a parameter:

```
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $stringXML);
```

instead of trying to parse it into an XML object.